# Append the values that don't exist in the other?

Tags: python, pandas, join

Merge col1 with col3 so values in the first go where col3 doesn't have values.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3, 4, 5],'col2': [12,2332,343,23,143]}
e=  {'col3': [3, 4], 'col4': [158,232]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = e)
df2 = pd.merge(d, e, left_on='col1', right_on='col3', how='left')
df2
```

df

```
col1    col2
0   1   12
1   2   2332
2   3   343
3   4   23
4   5   143
```

df1

```
col3    col4
0   3   158
1   4   232
```

It gives:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'dict'>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, ...)` in your code you define the two dataframes but then still use the dicts. Try merging the dataframes instead

Comment: ok thanks. This solves the problem with the valueerror but is this type of merge what is needed?

Comment: Can you show the desired output for this example?

Comment: can you please share what is your expected output dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed variables in change d,e  to df, df1

```
>>> pd.merge(df,df1, how='left', left_on='col1', right_on='col3')
   col1  col2  col3   col4
0     1    12   NaN    NaN
1     2  2332   NaN    NaN
2     3   343   3.0  158.0
3     4    23   4.0  232.0
4     5   143   NaN    NaN
```